.NET Framework - 4.7.2 - Azure Key Vault: Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.37.0.0
I am trying to retrieve secrets from Azure Key Vault using the following code:
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(vaultBaseUrl), credential);
KeyVaultSecret secret = client.GetSecret(secretName);

My project has the following dependencies:

Azure.Core - 1.40.0.0
Azure.Identity - 1.12.0
Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets - 4.6.0

Here is my configuration in the app.config:
<dependentAssembly>
<assemblyIdentity name="Azure.Core" publicKeyToken="92742159e12e44c8" 
  culture="neutral"/>
 <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.40.0.0" newVersion="1.40.0.0"/>
 </dependentAssembly>
 <dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Identity.Client" publicKeyToken="0a613f4dd989e8ae" 
  culture="neutral"/>
 <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.61.3.0" newVersion="4.61.3.0"/>
 </dependentAssembly>
 <dependentAssembly>
 <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Identity.Client.Extensions.Msal" 
  publicKeyToken="0a613f4dd989e8ae" culture="neutral"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.61.3.0" newVersion="4.61.3.0"/>
 </dependentAssembly>

When building the project, I get the following warning:
Unified Dependency "Azure.Core, Version=1.40.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8".
Using this version instead of original version "1.37.0.0" in "..\bin\Debug\Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets.dll" because AutoUnify is 'true'.
Resolved file path is "..\bin\Debug\Azure.Core.dll".
However, I encounter a runtime error:     // Error at client.GetSecret(secretName) : System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly
'Azure.Core, Version=1.37.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8' or one
of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the
assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'
var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(vaultBaseUrl), credential);  
KeyVaultSecret secret = client.GetSecret(secretName);

I tried downgrading Azure.Core to 1.37.0.0 but got a similar error with version 1.36.0.0:
System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.36.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'
And then downgraded to 1.36.0.0 but encountered with version 1.30.0.0
System.IO.FileLoadException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.30.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)'
Please help me to resolve this assembly loading issue?
Thank you for assistance.

maybe it's one if its dependencies? Try debugging with the use of the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event

Are you using Console app?

Below code and configuration worked for me by using below packages in packages.config
<packages>
    <package id="Azure.Identity" version="1.5.0" targetFramework="net472" />
    <package id="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net472" />
</packages>

HomeController.cs:
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
            string sct_name = "test";            
            var ri_key_VN = "https://rith9.vault.azure.net/";
            var ri_sc = new SecretClient(new Uri(ri_key_VN), new DefaultAzureCredential());
            var rith_sc = ri_sc.GetSecret(sct_name);
            ViewBag.Test = $"Hello Rithwik Bojja, the Secret name is  '{sct_name}' and Value is: {rith_sc.Value.Value}";
            return View();
        }
    }
}

Index.cshtml:
 <div>
 <section>
     <h2>Hello Rithwik the Secret Value</h2>
     <p>@ViewBag.Test</p>
 </section>
 </div?

Output:

